# Using regex or something else for searching for a file extension

Tags: regex, bash, cygwin

I have to create a bash script that will search a given directory for certain file extensions. The file extensions are in the form of .210 .110 .311 .211 and so on. I cannot do a mere "*.2* because there are file names that have that in the name. Is there a way to set a buffer after the "*.2*" so that the extension is only 3 characters in length? This will remove all the incorrect results from the search.

Right now I am using `find /cygdrive/x/Clients -name '*.210'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use wildcards. For all files with a 3-digit numeric extension, the following should suffice.

```
ls *.[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

If you want only extensions that begin with the number `2`, try this:

```
ls *.2[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: and in a find command, `find . -name '*.2[0-9][0-9]'`. If the following two characters are not necessarily digits, use `'*.2??'`

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, you just need to run the following in the target directory:

```
printf '%s\n' *.[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

The output won't include *dot-files*. If you want them you could enable the *dotglob* *bash* option. It would be safer to enable the *nullglob* option too (see comments by @c00kiemon5ter below).

Comment: if nothing matches then `printf` will print the pattern as a string, and that can be unsafe or unwanted. just something to watch out for..

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter, good point! Thanks! So the *nullglob* option need to be enabled too.

Answer (score 1):

you can user regular expressions if you pipe into grep

```
find /cygdrive/x/Clients | grep "\.2\d\d$"
```

but this is way slower than using wildcards as mentioned by Kurt S